# Wireshark only catches all kinds of packets but I only see ARP, 0x0800, 0x8912, etc. Why do I not see TCP or UDP packets?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

[image]

As you can see, Wireshark is definitely capturing a lot of TCP packets. But it is displaying only ARP, 0x0800, 0x8912, etc. If I put TCP as a filter I get blank. Why can't I see TCP packets?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/networking tech support.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found the solution on another site. Problem was that Wireshark was set to not recognize ipv4 and ipv6. But you can fix that by going to Analyze->Enabled Protocols and make sure that ipv4 and ipv6 are selected.

Comment: By default, it *is* set to recognize them, so you fixed whatever change you or somebody else made that caused it *not* to recognize them.

Comment: Hmm...I just downloaded and installed the new Wireshark....not sure how that happened